# perl assignment to hash in subroutine return gets weird

Tags: perl, hash, return, variable-assignment, subroutine

Running perl 5.12.4
Am getting disparity between result of a function when a hash is assigned within the return statement or beforehand. Easiest example is:

```
perl -e 'sub s1 {
  my @a=qw/b 1 c 2 a 3 a 4/;
  my %h=@a;
  return %h
  }
  print "@{[ s1()]}\n"'
c 2 a 4 b 1


perl -e 'sub s1 {
  my @a=qw/b 1 c 2 a 3 a 4/;
  my %h=@a;
  return %h=@a
  }
  print "@{[ s1()]}\n"'
c 2 c 2 a c
```

Why does (re)assigning to hash in return statement (2nd example) corrupt the returned hash?

Comment: Confirmed. This is truly weird. But when I ran the code on v14.2 or v16.3 it ran without issue → it seems to have been fixed, although I can't see any mention of related fixes in the perldeltas.

Comment: Running your second example on perl 5.16.2, I get `b 1 c 2 a 4`

Comment: This is a bit odd. I **can** replicate this on one of my machines: `This is perl 5, version 12, subversion 4 (v5.12.4) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level`

Comment: the return of hash/hash element assignments in list context have always been a little wonky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of a bug. It appears to have been fixed in 5.14.0. (Present in 5.12.4. Not present in 5.14.0)

Minimal test case:

```
perl -E"say %h = qw/b 1 c 2 a 3 a 4/"
```

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. I accept that my site needs to update its Perl version to 5.14. It is always nice to have one's sanity confirmed when the software foundations start to give way.

Comment: @RobN You mean update to at-least 5.14 (5.18 should be available in a week or-so. Although it may cause subtle bugs in your codebase to show their faces en-mass.)